# How to get some string with several condition

Tags: substring

```
 192.168.152.152 - - [22/Jan/2013:10:01:03 +0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 485 "-" "
 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"
```

this is sample of accesslog from server

can you help me please ?
How can i get information from string above ?
i want to get IP, Time, etc
thank you

Comment: PLEASE CLARIFY YOUR POST

Answer (score 0):

Ip Whois might have the information you're looking for

http://www.whatismyip.com/ip-tools/ip-whois-lookup/